# Opencv - Getting Pixel Coordinates from Feature Matching

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Can anyone help me? I want to get the x and y coordinates of the best pixels the feature matcher selects in the code provided, using c++ with opencv.

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher

Been looking around, but can't get anything to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [DMatch](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/de0/classcv_1_1DMatch.html) class gives you the distance between the two matching [KeyPoints](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html) (train and query). So, the best pairs detected should have the smallest distance. The tutorial grabs all matches that are less than 2*(minimum pair distance) and considers those the best.

So, to get the (x, y) coordinates of the best matches. You should use the `good_matches` (which is a list of `DMatch` objects) to look up the corresponding indices from the two different `KeyPoint` vectors (`keypoints_1` and `keypoints_2`). Something like:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
{
    Point2f point1 = keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt;
    Point2f point2 = keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt;
    // do something with the best points...
}
```

Comment: Some semicolons are missing :)

Comment: @ScottMarchant Thank you, good sir :) semi-colons have now been added.